# Zooming to full window width with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, zooming, transition

I'm trying to put a couple of image thumbnails in line and I want to be able to zoom them to window's full width by hovering on each image. I want the image to grow downwards. I got this far already:

https://jsfiddle.net/jimhoyle/tfkgcxx7/

```
div {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
div:hover {
  width: 95%;
}
```

Some specifications I'm looking for:
- thumbnails height: 5vw (or 200px)
- always keep the original aspect ratio
- neighbour thumbnails should stay in place while zooming
- zoomed image should not jump down to the next line
- images should show full file resolution when zoomed
- should work reasonably on both desktop and mobile (= click instead of hover)

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript for that.

You can achieve this in pure CSS using [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

Images can be forced to be aligned in all cases (`display: flex`) and then the targeted image container to be 10 times bigger than the others (`flex: 1` in regular case and `flex: 10` for the active case).

To mobile version could be setup using anchor and the `:target` CSS selector.

Here's an implementation of this solution.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 220px;
}

.container > a {
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  transition: flex 0.2s;
  line-height: 0;
}

.container > a:hover, .container > a:target {
  flex: 10;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#1" id="1">
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/1a/31/59/1a3159e4c899e2fd71b5fe58d0c2b5a9.jpg"/>
  </a>
  <a href="#2" id="2">
     <img src="https://ivymosquito.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/fox-eyes.jpg" />
  </a>
   <a href="#3" id="3">
     <img src="http://static.boredpanda.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/fox-faces-roeselien-raimond-red-fox.jpg"/>
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Flex seems very usable. However it's not exactly what I was looking for. I'm looking for a solution that zooms to (horizontal) fullscreen while thumbnails are all a certain height. Or actually 90% width is better as it's ok to leave the shrunken thumbnails that flex produces. As a bonus, it'd be great if height was limited to window size (fit width/height whichever maxes out first).

Comment: It's basic implementation for sure. You can achieve this using flex and my code as a starting point.